# Android App not compatible from play store but works in debug mode

Tags: android, permissions

The mobile I am going to talk about is Micromax A63, Android Version 4.2.2

When I was developing my app, I used it as a debug device and it worked fine. All the development is done on the system.

After development, I uploaded the apk to play store and registered as a beta tester. When I see the app in the play store it says "Your device is not compatible with this version"

I have checked the compatible list, interestingly this device is neither in Supported Devices List nor in Unsupported list.

I have the following in my gradle build

```
minSdkVersion 13
targetSdkVersion 22
```

The permissions i use in the app are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Help me understand what could be the issue.

Complete manifest file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ghr.ubietyapp" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/genie"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ProfileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:noHistory="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".OTPActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_otp"
            android:noHistory="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AttendanceActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_attendance" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UploadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_upload" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

thanks.

Comment: post your complete manifest.xml...

Comment: seems you have forget to add minimum sdk version and application version in Manifest.xml...

Comment: Well, your phone isn't exist in Google Play database, can you still download other apps?

Comment: yes of course, i am able to use all other apps (whatsapp, facebook, etc etc)

Comment: This is an indian phone. Did you publish your app in this Country?

Comment: This is an Indian phone and for your information, the app is available on play store on other devices.